# In the dimensional analysis, relationship of dimensionless parameter is?

Tags: dimensional-analysis

So if we do dimensional analysis about certain variables and determine the dimensionless parameters using recurring parameter,
let's say there is dimensionless parameter $\pi_1$, $\pi_2$, and $\pi_3$.
I learned that one parameter can be expressed using other two parameters
as
$$
\pi_1=F(\pi_2,\pi_3)\;.
$$
In this case, does $\pi_1$ always have to be expressed as a product of $\pi_2$ and $\pi_3$ considering each's exponents?
Can't it be an addition or summation of $\pi_2$ and $\pi_3$?

Comment: The relationship can be complicated, e.g. $\beta=\tanh r,\,\gamma=\cosh r,\,\gamma^2(1-\beta^2)=1$.

Comment: In terms of function application dimensionless parameters does not differ from other variables,- relationships between them can be any as with model used at hand.

Comment: So you mean that we can form dimensionless groups not just using multiplication but by using more complex ways? I kind of get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dimensional analysis you often obtain power laws from scaling considerations. But this should not mislead you to believe that this applies to the example equation you cite above.

What you have there is a relation between dimensionless quantities and without further info we cannot conclude anything about its functional form/it could be anything, as J.G. already commented. You'll sometimes find this in experiment, for example check out figures 1 and 2 in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%E2%80%93Weisbach_equation), where you have experimental values for such a relation between two dimensionless numbers, and it has a quite complex form due to a transition between laminar and turbulent flow regimes.

I would add that sometimes one is interested in limiting cases, one of the parameters being either very small or very large, and by performing an asymptotic expansion (most often a Taylor expansion) you end up with a sum of products again (in the particular limit only). :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please check the content I wrote under for clarification?