# How can we assume relationship of dimesionless group?

Tags: dimensional-analysis

[In the dimensional analysis, relationship of dimensionless parameter is?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/784346/in-the-dimensional-analysis-relationship-of-dimensionless-parameter-is/784376?noredirect=1#comment1762198_784376)

Above is the previous question I asked. I kinda understand that relationship of dimensionless group can be more complex.
[image]

However, I was taught using the above method to determine dimensionless groups. Then how should I interpret the last equation? It seems to me that the groups are related by multiplication. Is the method wrong or does the above equation doesn't actually mean equity but shows the fact that they are somewhat related?

Comment: Posting images of text or mathematics on SE is very strongly discouraged.  Please use a combination of text and [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead.  This also makes questions easier to read.